# How do I capture the Picklist Selected Event and write the code behind?

Tags: trigger, json, callout, class

To everyone,

I'm new to SFDC, but I'm not new to development.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

1.) Place Picklist on the Lead page with values RDC and Wire - this is done
2.) Capture the Picklist Selected Value when Selected is fired
3.) Capture the Lead details into a JSON Data
4.) Put the JSON data into a request message
5.) Make a callout to an External API based on Picklist value and send the JSON data as the request body

What kind of programming approach is best to solve this? Do I write an APEX trigger or class? How do I pull the Lead fieldnames and data values into a JSON data structure? How do I code the callout to the External API?

Thanks a ton in advance,
EC

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Stackexchange sites (like this one) generally want a single post to contain a single question because these sites aren't built to handle back-and-forth discussion like a traditional forum. The usual suggestion here for those new to Salesforce (or even just new to a part/feature thereof) is to go to https://trailhead.salesforce.com. Trailhead has more of a step-by-step approach, and it'll help you become familiar with the platform and its terminology. [The Developer Beginner trail](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/force_com_dev_beginner) is where I'd start.

Comment: I'm not super experienced with LWC (Lightning Web Components), but I don't think you'd be able to register an "onchange" event for a picklist (at least not when it's part of the standard "lightning record page" and/or the "page layout(s)" for a given SObject). A trigger (basically a database trigger, executed on Salesforce's servers, written in Apex) or a "Record-triggered Flow" is probably how you'd tackle this. Both are things that execute after clicking the save button in the UI. We can't make callouts directly from a trigger, so you'd need to use async Apex (`@future`, queueable, etc...)

Comment: The [Apex Integration Services](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services) and [Asynchronous Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex) trailhead modules will help with that. You may or may not need to write a SOQL query to get data. JSON is typically handled in Apex by `JSON.serialize()` and `JSON.deserialize()`/`JSON.deserializeUntyped()`.

Comment: Hope that gets you pointed in the right direction. If you go through all that and are running into specific issues, feel free to come back and ask a new question. Be sure to include what you've tried and point to a single, specific part that you're stuck on (and include any errors you're getting, verbatim). Even if the code isn't syntactically correct or working, including it helps people to identify and correct mistakes and misconceptions more quickly and accurately.